# Is there anyway to use the space on a datagrid column header where the sort button is

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have canUserSort set to false for all my columns.  When I resize a column or the header is too wide, the text dissappears behind where the sort arrow is normally displayed.  Is there anyway to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a copy of DataGrid style (there's an option in Expression Blend to create a new template from an existing style) and remove the visual elements that you don't need.

Then set your DataGrid's `Style` to be your new style. If you are using Silverlight 4 you can use implicit styling to replace the styles of all the DataGrids in your application. However, if some grids have the sorting enabled this wouldn't be a good idea.